# Possible to sell different contents with the same app on App Store?

Tags: iphone

I've been working on a book app, and hope to release it soon.

Here is my question:

Is it possible to sell two different contents with the same book app at App Store?

Naturally the two different books have two different contents with two different titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sell an app. And an app can have in-app content that a user can purchase. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Yes, it answered my question partially, just like 'iBooks', right?  Maybe I didn't ask properly. Let me rephrase it. "Will Apple accept my app if I could release my second book with the same book app?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with "dynamic" content.